# How to refer into certain cell in excel n times

Tags: excel

I want to add an entire column function which is able to refer into A1 4 times, then A2 4 times, A3 4 times etc.

Is there function for this kind of action?

Comment: Eg. A1 = 30, A2 = 50 --> function in column B --> B1 = 30, B2 = 30, B3 = 30, B4 = 30, B5 = 50, B6 = 50, B7 = 50, B8 = 50

Comment: Just create your function, that take a reference of a cell and do your stuff 4 time on this reference. Then just call on the entire column the function you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Row 1 and copied down:

```
INT((ROW()-1)/4)
```

will return four `0`s, four `1`s, four `2`s and so on. This can be fed into the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function to produce the desired result:

```
 =OFFSET(A$1,INT((ROW()-1)/4),,)
```